# What is the mean difference between 取引先との付き合い方 and 取引先の付き合い方?

Tags: grammar

What is the mean difference between 取引先との付き合い方 and 取引先の付き合い方?

Thank for support me.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54461/what-is-this-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ae/54466#54466

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange (JLSE).  We would love to help you.  Our answers to your question will be much more helpful if you included what your understanding of the two sentences is.  That way we can cater our answers to your needs.  Would you mind expanding your question to include that detail?

Comment: Welcome to the forum! I have never seen the 2nd version (取引先の付き合い方),  I would personally have thought that the answer is "the difference is that the 1st one is correct and the 2nd one is incorrect" ;-) [Seriously, could the 2nd one just be a mistake?]. My Japanese skills are far from those of the natives, so sending this comment also hoping someone corrects me if I was wrong. Theoretically (although far fetched) I guess the 2nd one could be used when referring to the way one's supplier is interacting with its stakeholders, but this would at least need to be preceed by some context explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know how との, への, からの and so on work yet, please learn it first: [Grammar of との, what is the meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17738/5010) /  [Why can we use の after へ and から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/5010)

So, 取引先**との**付き合い方 means "how to get along with your business partners" or "the way to deal with business partners". Note that 付き合い方 is a noun which by itself means something like 'communication methods'. This is the recommended choice if you want to build a formal and unambiguous sentence.

取引先**の**付き合い方 is an ambiguous expression since の is a generic linking particle that has a wide variety of functions, one of which is to mark the subject of an action. It can mean the same thing as 取引先**との**付き合い方, but it can also mean "how the business partner deals with (us or someone else)".