# Meaning of との in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-の

What's the meaning of との in this sentence?

```
わしが後衛との壁になろう。
```

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54461/what-is-this-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ae/54466#54466

Answer (score 1):

It's a case particle と ("with" as in "face with something" or "fight with someone") followed by a noun-linking particle の. See:

- [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010)
- [What is this との?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54461/5010)

Assuming this sentence is said in a common fantasy RPG-like setting, 後衛との壁 refers to either of:

- the wall (tank) that blocks ranged attacks (e.g., arrows) coming from rear members of the enemy
- the wall (tank) that guards rear members (e.g. supporters, healers) of the ally

The former is more likely but it may mean the latter depending on the context.